# How do I program digital pins on arduino uno?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno

I'm trying to make a microcontroller with an arduino. I am supplying with +5volt from the arduino, sending it to an NC button (so i can manually decide when to output a certain timed pulse). After the button it goes to a pin that I have set as an inPin (pin8). Then I want the program to make pin 7 HIGH(with a delay), and then it goes to a transistor.

This is the code I tried making (I know almost nothing about coding):

```
int ledPin = 7;
int inPin = 8;
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
}



void loop() 
{
if (inPin=HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
}
    delay (500);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
```

---

For some reason the outPin is HIGH all the time. I remembered to hook up a resistor to GND so the digital pin would stay LOW when supposed to be LOW.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vladimir's answer is correct. Moreover I HIGHLY suggest you to start looking at the examples in the arduino IDE to see how things work. And try to find at least some basic tutorials...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(inPin=HIGH)` is a mistake, first of all use `"=="` instead of `"="`. ALso you need to READ input pin state: `int invalue = digitalRead(inPin);`

Also, all pins by default coonfigured as inputs, so you don't need use `pinMode(inPin, INPUT);`

After those changes your code will look like:

```
int ledPin = 7;
int inPin = 8;
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  if (digitalRead(inPin)==HIGH) digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
```